# google docs tampering

Tags: google-docs

NOTE: sorry as this is not a programming question but i am not aware about the site to post this query. so i thought any of you could help me out with this.

QUERY:
i have created an excel sheet using google docs to help users to fill their details online. but my problem is that every user has access to this sheet. 
some users tampered the sheet and deleted all data.
is there a mechanism provided by google docs to prevent tampering of data?
what should i do?
should i use something else to store user's data so that no user can tamper the data?

Comment: Don't give the users read-write access to the data?

Comment: well the users ought to have read-write access as they are the ones whose data need to be stored, but my problem is that no user should be able to modify other user's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Google Form function and set your Google spreadsheet to private

Answer (score 0):

If you go to *Data > Protected Sheets and Ranges* you can adjust the settings of who can monkey with the data. Probably the best thing to do, however, is to use a Google Form, which will allow you to gather data in a structured format and dump it to the spreadsheet. That is really your best bet...